# Make a file more readable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say we have a file with the following inside:

```
{{{banana},{kinky},{bronze-spaghetti,
definitly-not},{legitimate-style, witness,
drunk}}}
```

I wanted to rearrange this file so that it look like this:

```
{{{banana},
{kinky},
{bronze-spaghetti,definitly-not},
{legitimate-style, witness, drunk}}}
```

Notice that each line ends with `},` except for the last one. Now my question is how would I do this?

Comment: What file do you mean? source file?

Comment: Just a file that's in the same directory as the script

Comment: So, essentially, you want to insert a `\n` after each `},` sequence?

Comment: `print("""{{{banana},{kinky},{bronze-spaghetti,
definitly-not},{legitimate-style, witness,
drunk}}}""".replace("\n", "").replace("},", "},\n"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find the regex "}," and insert after it a new line

edit:
as jDo suggested, you can do something like that:

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data=infile.read()
with open('out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(data.replace("\n", "").replace("},", "},\n"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) (triple quotes for multi-line strings):

```
original_text = """{{{banana},{kinky},{bronze-spaghetti, definitly-not},{legitimate-style, witness, drunk}}}"""
reformatted = original_text.replace("\n", "").replace("},", "},\n")
print(reformatted)
```

This can easily be done in the shell:

```
>>> my_str = """{{{banana},{kinky},{bronze-spaghetti,
... definitly-not},{legitimate-style, witness,
... drunk}}}"""
>>> 
>>> my_str = my_str.replace("\n", "").replace("},", "},\n")
>>> 
>>> print(my_str)
{{{banana},
{kinky},
{bronze-spaghetti,definitly-not},
{legitimate-style, witness,drunk}}}
>>>
```